# Every command gives several warnings in R even though the code compiles

Tags: r

For the past week or so, every time I've typed a command in any R Markdown document (even simple commands like `print(2 + 2)`, I've gotten the following list of warning messages:

Warning in (function (..., list = character(), pos = -1, envir = as.environment(pos),  :
  object 'print.htmlwidget' not found

Warning in (function (..., list = character(), pos = -1, envir = as.environment(pos),  :
  object 'print.html' not found

Warning in (function (..., list = character(), pos = -1, envir = as.environment(pos),  :
  object 'print.shiny.tag' not found

Warning in (function (..., list = character(), pos = -1, envir = as.environment(pos),  :
  object 'print.shiny.tag.list' not found

Warning in (function (..., list = character(), pos = -1, envir = as.environment(pos),  :
  object 'print.knit_asis' not found

Warning in (function (..., list = character(), pos = -1, envir = as.environment(pos),  :
  object 'print.knit_image_paths' not found

The warnings appear both in the console and below the code chunk in which the command appears. The correct output still appears above the warnings (e.g. when I do `print(2 + 2)`, I get 4 followed by those error messages), and I can still compile and knit documents, but it is quite a nuisance. I'm not sure what I could have done to cause this. I've tried closing and restarting R, making a new markdown document, and re-downloading R Studio, but none of these attempted solutions has worked. Does anyone have any ideas as to why this might be happening and how I could go about fixing it?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling R?

Comment: Some of the functions mentioned are from the [htmltools](https://github.com/rstudio/htmltools) package; all look knitting/Shiny related. Most likely they're being used by RStudio to display the results of RMarkdown code chunks, but the installation is failing somehow. It may be a version issue; make sure R and your packages are all at least reasonably recent.

Comment: Warning != Error. These are all warnings, not errors.

Comment: Sorry, my background in the terminology is pretty poor; I've updated the post to reflect that the issue is warning-related, not error-related. I will also look into the versions of the packages I'm using. Thanks for the help